Exercise similar to the ballot box model
Consider the following problem
A box contains 10 bulbs of which 6 are new and 4 are used, 4 bulbs are selected at random without replacement until a used one is removed. I want to determine the probability that exactly 3 bulbs need to be selected to obtain the first used bulb.
Let A:3 bulbs are randomly selected, B:The i-th bulb is used, I think what we want to determine is:
$$P(B_{1}|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B_{1})}{P(A)}$$
Noting that $P(A)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$, but what about the intersection, here I want to calculate the probability that three are taken at random, and among them the first one is used, I have thought of something like:
$$P(A \cap B_1)=\frac{\binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$
But I'm not entirely convinced, I feel I leave cases out when calculating for intersection, any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

This describes a sequence of four conditionally independent selections.  You can easily compute the probabilities at each stage: multiplying them gives the answer.  If that's not perfectly clear, draw the probability tree, as I recently illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/648497/919 for a similar (but slightly more complicated) problem.

The key is the phrase "exactly 3 bulbs need to be selected to obtain the first used bulb".  This  means that the third bulb is used, and the first two are not.  If, for example, the first used bulb was the second one selected, you wouldn't have needed to select exactly 3 bulbs to obtain the first used one.  So... What is the probability that the first one is new?  The probability that the second one is new given that the first one was?  ... and so on.

The way you are using $P$ does not seem to be compatible with the way it is generally used. If you have

A:3 bulbs are randomly selected

Then, based on the problem description, $P(A)=1$. If, you meant to write "A:3 specific bulbs are randomly selected (let's say they are numbered and numbers 2, 3, and 9 are selected)", then $P(B_1|A)$ is not what the problem is asking you to calculate.
Regardless, this is what you want:
$$P(N_1, N_2, U_3)=P(N_1)P(N_2|N_1)P(U_3|N_2,N_1)$$
where $N_i$/$U_i$ are statements saying the $i$th bulb is new/used, respectively.
Since this is without replacement, we have:
$$P(N_1)P(N_2|N_1)P(U_3|N_2,N_1)=\frac{6}{10}\times\frac{5}{9}\times\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Why does your analysis consider only three bulbs when the question concerns four?

@whuber The statement of the problem is a little confusing to me. I understood it as asking the probability of the 3rd choice being the first used bulb. Changing this to the probability of the 4th choice being the first used isn't much different.

I agree it's confusing.  A good way to deal with a situation like that is to start your answer by stating your understanding of the question.
